# Is there a way to get Moodle plugin installation date and user?

Tags: moodle

Is there a way (screen or database) in Moodle 3  to know who and when a plugin has been installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the details in table `config_plugins`

`SELECT * FROM mdl_config_plugins WHERE NAME = 'version';`

Comment: This only clarifies that a plugin has been installed. The same plugin may have been installed several times, therefore you probably  also need to filter out the last time the plugin has been installed (that is, updated) if this is what ben.IT wants. Also, the first question has not been answered yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the config log under: yourmoodle.com/report/configlog/index.php

this will show you the date, user, plugin and setting change. If you sort by the 'plugin' column and find the page where the plugin shows up, you'll know who installed/updated settings for it. When you install a plugin, any default setting that is being saved, will relate it to the user who installed it.